# Spring Boot logs static loaded data

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have static pages in my Spring Boot project. When these pages have been loaded I see in logs information about each request to each file:

```
10.31.123.79 - - [07/Mar/2016:16:12:54 -0500] "GET /views/StrategySort.html HTTP/1.1" 200 6873
10.31.123.79 - - [07/Mar/2016:16:12:55 -0500] "GET /js/ng-sortable.js HTTP/1.1" 200 45579
```

I didn't find answer how to switch it off.

Who knows? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Springboot uses some logging framework. It is either logback or log4j
You just have to turn off logs that are not interesting to you by mentioning the package of this classes. By the way what is the problem to see this logs?

Comment: There is a mess in log. A lot of messages of loaded files. I figured it out. I use one corporate module. In that module there is one additional logback configuration. And there was configuration for this logging:
<if condition='!property("headless").equals("true") || property("EnableConsoleOutput").equals("true")'>
  <then>
   <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
     <pattern>common</pattern>
    </encoder>
   </appender>

   <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
  </then>
 </if>